# Output xsd sequence information after simple element with dataset

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xsd, dataset

I work with the xsd.exe to create a `DataSet` class for vb.net. All output data are contained inside this `DataSet` so I can use the `DataSet.writexml(writer as XMLWriter)` method to output the data to a file.

Originally I wanted to output xml data in the following pattern:

```
<customoutput>
    <zzz>Serial</zzz>
    <www1>Info1</www1>
    <www2>Info2</www2>
    <wwwn>Infon</wwwn>
</customoutput>
```

So I thought, describing the `<www/>` sequence is quite impossible, because node names have to be static.

For that reason I decided trying output this XML:

```
<customoutput>
    <zzz>Serial</zzz>
    <www value="1">Info1</www>
    <www value="2">Info2</www>
    <www value="n">Infon</www>
</customoutput>
```

So I create an XSD file to create this xml. I made it, due to my lack in XSD knowledge, by Visual Studio automatically

```
        <xs:element name="customoutput">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="zzz" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="www">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

The strange thing is: By using `DataSet.writexml(writer as XMLWriter)`, I get the output:

```
<customoutput>
    <zzz>Serial</zzz>
</customoutput>
<www value="1">Info1</www>
<www value="2">Info2</www>
<www value="n">Infon</www>
```

Comment: WriteXml and ReadXml does not work well on complicated Xml structures.  You have attributes which are causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XElement output = new XElement("customoutput", new object[] {
                new XElement("zzz", "Serial"),
                new XElement("www", new object[] { new XAttribute("value", 1), "Info1"}),
                new XElement("www", new object[] { new XAttribute("value", 2), "Info2"}),
                new XElement("www", new object[] { new XAttribute("value", "n"), "Infon"})
            });
            output.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I thought about a solution like this. The only disadvantage is of cause, that I cannot use XSD anymore. I did like the idea of sharing the XSD file with the develper, who is implementing the XML reading.

Comment: You could manually create the xsd; or make classes a use serialization and then generate the  xsd from the classes.  Or change the format of your xml to be compatible with the dataset methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSD would be a lot simpler you omit the sequence number. I would define the content of the complex type as a sequence, and allow the tag 'Info' to repeat (`maxOccurs="unbounded"`). An XML schema sequence is implicitly ordered so the sequence numbers would not be required. Then you could use your original technique, and share the XSD.